# How not to trigger multiple form divs with a single click action

Tags: jquery

I've got multiple hidden forms on my page; each one should be triggered by a corresponding span element.  The span elements all share a class, and I would like for only the corresponding form to show in a modal window when a specific span element is clicked (I'm using easyModal.js jQuery plugin for my modal windows).  My current setup is loading all forms into separate modal windows instead of just the one form that corresponds to the one span item clicked.

An example code for my span element would be:

```
<span class="open-modalwindow">Find by List ID</span>
```

Each of my forms is similiar to this one, with very minor changes to each:

```
<div id="submission_byListID" class="modalform" style="display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 8; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -134.5px;">
<div class="header">
    <h3>Search by List ID</h3>
</div>
<form action="">
    <div class="txt">
        <label for="ListID">ListID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="bylistID_input">
    </div>
    <div class="btn clearfix">
        <a class="close" href="#">Submit</a>
        <a class="close cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The jQuery function I'm using to handle the clicks to the span elements is:

```
$('.open-modalwindow').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
    $("div[class*='modalform']").trigger('openModal');
   });
});
```

I understand why the behavior exists, after all I am saying that for each item with class of 'open-modalwindow', open the modal window for each item with a class name containing 'modalform'.

As I'll end up with around 20 different forms on the page, I was trying to avoid having to give each span element a unique ID and have a separate jQuery click handler like:

```
$('#SomeSpanElementID').click(function(){
   $('#SomeFormElementID').trigger('openModal');
});
```

Is there an easy way to streamline this instead of explicitly stating 20 separate jQuery click handler functions to display my 20 different forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a way to associate the span with the form. You can for example use a data attribute to specify the id:

```
<span class="open-modalwindow" data-form="submission_byListID">Find by List ID</span>
```

Then you can use the data to find the form. You don't need to use `each` to loop through the elements and bind a separate handler for each, you can bind the same event handler to all of them:

```
$('.open-modalwindow').click(function(){
  $("#" + $(this).data('form')).trigger('openModal');
});
```

Comment: Man oh man, Guffa.  You were on the money with this one; it works beautifully!  Thanks alot!!